# Creating RPM package for shell script

Tags: bash, unix, rpm, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

Good day.

I'm have been assigned a task for creating a RPM package for our agent which I never done before.

This agent consist a shell script and some files.

```
The steps to install our agent is,
1) Extract the agent .gz file.
2) Create a specific folder for this agent.
3) Create a specific user for the agent and assign this user to the created folder in step 2.
3) Run 'install.sh' script which located in specific folder.
4) Done.
```

Question is does this steps can be written into .spec file and does this agent can be packaging into RPM style?

Because I can see mostly RPM software written in C and there are step of 'build', 'configure', 'make install', etc. Just afraid if .spec file only can be executed for this kind of build and install method.

Comment: Can `install.sh` be passed a custom install path?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams May I know what do you mean by "passed a custom install path"?

Comment: E.g. `install.sh /install/here/instead`

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Nope..we can just run install.sh in the directory which this script located...Ex:- ./var/adm/user/install.sh